# Numpy multi-dimensional array slicing

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing

I have a 3-D NumPy array with shape (100, 50, 20). I was trying to slice the third dimension of the array by using the index, e.g., from 1 to 6 and from 8 to 10.

I tried the following code, but it kept reporting a syntax error.

`newarr [:,:,1:10] = oldarr[:,:,[1:7,8:11]]`

Comment: `[1:7,8:11]` is an invalid use of slices.  The error was caught by the interpreter, but it also has no meaning to `numpy`.  That's a discontinuous set of locations, which has to be enumerated as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate slice objects:

```
newarr [:,:,1:10] = oldarr[:,:,np.r_[1:7,8:11]]
```

---

*Example*:

```
np.r_[1:4,6:8]
array([1, 2, 3, 6, 7])
```